# How big a footprint might my website have

Tags: hyper-v, web-hosting

I'm about to go live with a new E-commerce site and have very little (read no) real knowledge on hosting.

Our old site is happily sitting on shared hosting, receiving about 300 users a day. We are expeting / hoping the new site would quickly receive upto 1000 users a day with around 5000 page impressions a day.

The site is ASP.NET MVC with a SQL Server Database. I'm on a fairly tight budget for hosting and am wondering what sort of service I should be looking for to meet my requirements and leave me a little room if the site is more successful than expected.

My uneducated Idea was to go for a Hyper-V VPS with 15gb of space, 300gb bandwith a month, 512mb guaranteed ram, and SQL Server 2008 Express installed. Would that be ok?

Thanks for any help you can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to predict your system requirements based on pure speculation of user numbers.  Most of it has to do with the weight of your site, and how much work each user makes the server do.  If it is a heavy site with lots of processing and database queries involved, each user has a much higher impact than something more static.

That being said, I think you are heading in the right direction.

Having experience with this sort of thing in the past, a VPS is a good route to go.  Make sure you get a relatively modest VPS to start with, to save money, with a provider who can dynamically allocate you more resources on demand, so the VPS can grow with you.

After some time, if all goes well for you and your business, your VPS can easily grow with your needs.

If you monitor it carefully, you will be able to predict when you might need to add another server/vps to your farm, or move off to a purely dedicated box.

I have had very good experiences with [Layered Tech](http://www.layeredtech.com/cloud-computing/virtual-machine-hosting/microsoft-hyper-v-virtual-machine/) in the past, and I actually have two VPS with them currently.  Give them a look.